# Reading a JPEG file perl

Tags: perl

I am working on a web-page that takes a JPEG file. Is there a way to read the actual JPEG file itself ?

I know the read - in perl can take the file handle of the JPEG. But I want to know is there a way to slurp the whole file itself without a file name? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: And how you get the JPG file without a file name?

Comment: The data has to come from *somewhere*. If you don't have a filename, what do you have? (As a general rule of thumb, questions need to tell people what you have, not what you lack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have many questions, but if you need to slurp using a Perl file handle from an already-opened file without knowledge of the file name then write something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub slurp_handle {
  my ($handle) = @_;
  local $/;
  return readline $handle;
}

chdir "$ENV{USERPROFILE}\\Pictures" or die $!;

open my $fh, '<', 'images.jpg' or die $!;

print slurp_handle $fh;
```

Comment: Okie! I technically have a filename. but its is stored in the Cache in a different name.I am now sorted Thanks!